# geting max/min lat and long in openstreetmaps?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps-api-2

my question is simply, what is openstreet map's equivalent for google maps map.getBounds() function, to get the max/min lat and long?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a JS-API(e.g. OpenLayers)

The method to use there is [**getExtent()**](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.getExtent)